# PHP. call static method of class which class name saved in static variable of other class?

Tags: php, oop, static

for example i have 2 Classes:
"`Main`" and "`Dll_Main_Bla`".

`Class "Dll_Main_Bla"` has static methods only! for example

```
public static function doIt($argument){return $argument*2;};
```

Inside `Main` I have static variable
`public static $dll_bla = 'Dll_Main_Bla';`

In non-static method of `Class Main` I want To call:

```
$x = Dll_Main_Bla::doIt(2);
```

but I want to centralize initializing of my Dlls and call them like here:

`// how to ???
$x = self::$dll_bla::doIt(2);`

Yes, it doesn't works, but you might understand what exactly I want. :)
How would I write that line to make it workable?
Thanks for any proposition!

Comment: Sounds to me like your ***real*** problem is having to work with badly written code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `call_user_func_array()` ([PHP reference link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php))

Small test example:

```
<?php

class Main {
    public static $dll_bla = 'Dll_Main_Bla';

    public function init() {
        $x = call_user_func_array(array(self::$dll_bla, 'doIt'),array(2));
        echo $x;
    }
}

class Dll_Main_Bla {
    public static function doIt($argument) {
        return $argument*2;
    }
}

$main = new Main;
$main->init();
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider doing this:

```
<?php
class Dll_Main_Bla {
    public static function toBeCalled($anyParam) {
        return 'Elo, ' . $anyParam;
    }
}

class Main {
    public static $dll_bla = 'Dll_Main_Bla';

    public function test() {
        $className = Main::$dll_bla;
        $x = $className::toBeCalled('Vincent');

        return $x;
    }
}

$main = new Main;
echo $main->test(); //should do what you expect it to do
```

Comment: Yes! It works! Thanks! But is it possible to call without temporary variable $className? Want to see shorter solution.
${self::$dll_bla}::toBeCalled('Vincent') or something like that...

Comment: for shorter way, please check @RichardBernards solution using call_user_func_array

Comment: No, thanks! Your solution looks like writes easier :)

Comment: @LINKeRxUA his solution does have a much larger footprint... Hence my solution ;)

Comment: @RichardBernards, I prefare androidavid solution, thank you for helping too!